# How to change the value of a field depending on answer of other model item

Tags: c#, razor

I need to add some form of @If to this piece of code, if ContactMe = "No" then display "user does not want to be contacted" otherwise display the email ID and name.

I cant for life of me work this out properly, I would be very grateful for a point in right direction

```
  <th>
            @{ var email = "mailto:" + item.EmailID;}
            <a href="@email">@item.FullName  @item.Position</a>

        </th>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see `ContactMe` variable or attribute, are you sure it's not possible with `@if (ContactMe == "No") { } else { }`?

Comment: hi, thanks for response I have tried this, it just doesn't pick it up! :) <td>

                @{ var email2 = "mailto:" + item.EmailID;}
                @if (item.ContactMe == "No")
    {
            <p>  Not to be contacted</p>
}
else
{
            <a href="@email2">@item.FullName  @item.Position</a>
}
<td>

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the logic conditions in Razor. Following link will provide you with the needed knowledge.

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_cs_logic.asp

Comment: Thank you I will follow this

Answer (score 0):

this has worked now thank you

```
                @{ var Contact = "Member not to be contacted";}

                @if (item.ContactMe == "Yes")
        {
            <a href="@email">@item.FullName  @item.Position</a>
}

    else
    {
            @Contact
}
```